# proper output not given by SQL Count Statement

Tags: php, mysql, count

I executed the  following SQL count query and the  accomaniying code  to  try to get  the number of searches done along with the  search date for a particular course.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'Number Of Enquiries'],
                   <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 
                         $cid=$row['CourseID']; ?>

          ['<?php echo $row['Date']?>', <?php
          $sql1=("
            SELECT COUNT(CourseID) 
    FROM EnquiryDetails WHERE CourseID='$cid'");
          $res=mysql_query($sql1,$conn);
echo $res;
```

But still,the page source shows the following,where there should be a number some Resource #4 or something is shown.what did i do wrong?
      ['Date', 'Number Of Enquiries'],

```
  ['2013-08-17', Resource id #4],
 ]);
```

Comment: You had not fetched the query result. P.S.: You cannot do that in javascript. Make you queries outside the js and only echo vars in js

Comment: i did  the  queries within php tags.btw,what code should i type to get it right?

Comment: You write them in PHP tags, but you know one is executed on server-side, while another on client side. You cannot trigger PHP functions with javascript. You should use mysql_result and echo it, if you expect only one row, ot use like above mysql_fetch_array and iterate through it. If you to the second, your count should be aliased e.g: `COUNT(col) as cnt`, so then $row['cnt'] should be echoed

Comment: i get  this error Wrong parameter count for mysql_result()

Comment: A Sherlock Holmes would investigate mysql_query function up to the **manual page**, I believe

Comment: the purpose of mysql_result is to put the already executed query in it, but you should expect only one result. @YourCommonSense again +1, you are my favourite one in this site :)

Comment: yeah.only one result should  be given.a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql1,$conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res)
echo $row[0];
```

`mysql_query` returns a resultset ressource, that represents a table of the result. You need to read the content using other functions, like `mysql_fetch_row`, but there are many more.

Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After  executing `mysql_query` you need to fetch results from that.

Read the documents here [fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

BTW stop using `mysql` functions they are deprecated use either `PDO` or `mysqli` functions.